# Returning data to subscribe from observable in angular

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am trying to return data to my component and then trigger a route with data from service passed as a param. I think i'm using observables incorrectly and am confused if data can be returned to the subscribe or if I should be triggering routing from the service provider. The issue with triggering route from service provider is that the scope changes inside extractData. Can I access this.router from within extractData()? The  component is set up like this on submit of a form:

Updated:

Component:

```
private dataFromServer: ShortFormModel;
onSubmit(shortForm: any) {
    if (!shortForm) { return; }
    const formModel = this.shortForm.value;
    this.shortFormService.create(formModel)
    .subscribe(body => { this.dataFromServer = body; console.log(body) })
  }) 
 }
```

service provider:

```
create(shortForm: any): Observable<ShortFormModel> {
 let headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
 let options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});

 return this.http.post(this.preCheckUrl, shortForm, options)
  .map((res) => this.extractData(res))
  .catch(
  (error: any): Promise<any>=> {
    this.router.navigate(['/error', error]);
    return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
  }
 )
}

private extractData(res: Response) {
  let body = res.json();
  this.router.navigate(['/apply', body.appId])
  return body|| { };
}
```

response payload:

```
{  
  "offer":{  
   "id":null,
   "amount":null,
},
"dupes":true,
"appId":53
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're indeed right, when using

```
.map(this.extractData)
```

scope is changing inside `extractData`. You would have to wrap the call to `this.extractData` inside a lambda/fat-arrow function to preserve scope, like this:

```
.map((res) => this.extractData(res))
```

Comment: Perfect, that works! As for the other part of my question, how would I return data back to the component? Right now, the only way I can seem to access the response is from extractData.

Comment: You can access the data from "within" the observable from inside the subscribe-method's success callback, like this:

     ` .subscribe(res => {    
        this.componentProperty = res;
        this.router.navigate(['/apply', res])
    })`

Comment: This makes sense, however, the 'res' in subscribe is just an empty object even though their is a response. See my updated implementation above.

Comment: Ok, so how does your response-payload look? You are trying to return `body.data`, so does your response-payload have a property `data`?

Comment: Updated with response payload

Comment: Ok, with that payload you would need to access the payload something like:   
`this.router.navigate(['/apply', body.appId])`   
and   
`return body || { };`   
(inside extractData())

Comment: Updated subscribe to look for body that is returned from extract data. This solution works.

Comment: Thanks ;)
you'd have to return only `body` from `extractData`, not `body.data` though

Comment: Yes, correct. Forgot to update the service provider code update.

Comment: is it possible to leverage  angular's  reportProgress option with my current setup?